# Issues with union and memory aligment

Tags: c++, c, memory, unions

i'm currently working on a Port of Embedded Code (on a Freescale S12) so GNU and i hava a issue with unions.
i have the following union

```
typedef signed short        sint16;
typedef signed long         sint32;

typedef union
{
    sint32 Akku;
    sint16 AkkuHigh;
    sint16 AkkuLow;
} akku_type;
```

and i want to access the highest 2 byte of the union. The Problem is, that both AkkuHigh and AkkuLow have the same starting adress as Akku. It seems to be compiler specific. My Questions are:
Is the there a Compiler Flag which changes the behaviour of the union?
Can **atribute**((align (2))) help me?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Pack the `high` and `low` fields in an inner anonymous `struct`. Strictly speaking it's not portable, but it should work.

Comment: Why did you expect them to have different addresses?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae: C allows it, and it's a common C++ extension. Wonder why the committee didn't cave in and legitimize it...

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae: Padding at the *beginning* of a struct? Where did you get that standards-breaking compiler? (And non-neccessary padding *after* a member is just weird, and not yet found in the wild.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all of `Akku`, `AkkuHigh`, `AkkuLow` have the same address. This is how [unions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) work in C. By the look of it, you intended to make an union with a 32-bit member and a member that is a struct of two 16-bit members instead. What you wrote is not the way to achieve it. Try instead:

```
typedef union
{
    sint32 Akku;
    struct s {
      sint16 AkkuHigh;
      sint16 AkkuLow;
    } representation;
} akku_type;
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `AkkuHigh` will be the high byte and `AkkuLow` will be the low byte? Couldn't the compiler decide to switch them around?

Comment: @Unapiedra The guarantee is that the addresses of the members of a struct are in order. What these addresses correspond to is implementation-dependant (typically, this depends on the endianness of the target architecture. The struct as written works for most big-endian architectures).

Comment: @Unapiedra: Switching them around is not allowed, but adding arbitrary (implementation-defined) amounts of padding after `struct`-members is (*not* before them).

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition of the union can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278228/4265352).

`atribute(align(2))` will definitely help you if you compile this on a 32bit or 64bit architecture. Also, on 64bit `sizeof(sint32)` is `8` (64 bits).

Depending on the endian-ness of the architecture, you may need to swap `AkkuHigh` and `AkkuLow`.

Comment: Just mention that's valid C but not C++, though a common extension in C++.

Comment: What exactly is not valid C++? The unnamed struct?

Comment: Yes. The unnamed member of anonymous type. Ping me when you corrected it.

Comment: Got it. Removed the definition of the union entirely, it is described well in the other answer.

Comment: I would keep it and just add that disclaimer. It's the better solution in C, and arguably also in C++, considering how common that extension is.